# Why does the Doctor travel with companions from our era?

Tags: doctor-who

It seems as if the Doctor travels with companions in the same era and time that the show was broadcasted (e.g. he meets up with Clara in 2012, when the episode was broadcasted). If the TARDIS can travel anywhere and any time, what keeps him favoring the Earth, the human race, at this particular time?

Might be related: [Why does the Doctor favor Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/why-does-the-doctor-favor-earth)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of The Doctor's companions are not contemporary humans. From the beginning, [Susan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Susan_Foreman) was Galifreyan. More recently, [Jack](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Harkness) was born in the 51st century. In between, we had [Vicki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vicki_Pallister), [Steven](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Taylor), [Katarina](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Katarina), [Sara Kingdom](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sara_Kingdom), [Jamie](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jamie_McCrimmon), [Victoria](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_Waterfield), [Zoe](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Zoe_Heriot), [Leela](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Leela), the various incarnations of [K9](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/K9), [Romana](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Romana), [Adric](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Adric), [Nyssa](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Nyssa), [Kamelion](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Kamelion), and [Turlough](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vislor_Turlough). Many of the companions in other media also fit the bill, a handful of whom were made in-arguably cannon in [Night of The Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Night_of_the_Doctor). The almost or non-human and/or non-contemporary companions are in the minority, but it is a significant minority.

That said, out of universe, a significant role of the companions is to bridge the viewer's world to The Doctor's. Writer after writer has used the current companion to ask "What is it, Doctor?" It is easier to frame this question in a time and place useful for exposition if the companion asking the question shares a frame of reference with the viewer. Contemporary episodes save on set construction without having to overuse the local rock quarries. It hasn't hurt the ratings to have eye candy on the show, either.

In universe, Earth seems to be his favorite planet, and contemporary humans stick our noses where they don't belong, i.e., The Tardis.

Comment: I guess that make sense then, thanks! (Also realized I overlooked a lot of companions...)

Comment: To be fair, all of the Nu Who companions are humans from 21st century Earth. All the others listed were from Old Who when the budgets were bigger and effects were easier. Hey... waitaminute!